# onchange and onselect not working properly on ipad and iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad

```
$ext.on('change',".word_zooming",function(){
    triggercall("zoom"+$(".word_zooming ").val(),"zoomRadioSet");
    $(this).Zoom('#editor_text , #textbox_header , #textbox_footer' , 1);
});
```

This is the code i am using where ext is a containter variable

Comment: What kind of element is `.word_zooming`?

Comment: i just want to append any div onchange of select tag.

Comment: Add your HTML to the question. Use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make the code in the question executable.